# Flutter Internationalization: How to access to nested data in json

Tags: flutter, internationalization

I want to know how to access to nested data in json.

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Information.about');
```

`en.json`

```
{  
  "Information" : {
      "about": "About"
  }

}
```

I tried like the way above but it cannot access to the nested data.

And here is translate method.

```
  class AppLocalizations {
      final Locale locale;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  // Static member to get access to the delegate from 'main.dart' file
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate = _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  Map<String, String> _localizedValues;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    // Load a language JSON file from the 'i18n' folder
    String value = await rootBundle.loadString('i18n/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(value);
    _localizedValues = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });
    return true;
  }

  String translate(String key) {
    // Returns a localized text
    return _localizedValues[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where your en.json is in your code?

Comment: @Morez `root/i18n/en.json`

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer!

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924513

```
  Map flattenTranslations(Map<String, dynamic> json, [String prefix = '']) {
    final Map<String, String> translations = {};
    json.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
      if (value is Map) {
        translations.addAll(flattenTranslations(value, '$prefix$key.'));
      } else {
        translations['$prefix$key'] = value.toString();
      }
    });
    return translations;
  }

  Future<bool> load() async {
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/i18n/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    _localizedStrings = flattenTranslations(jsonMap);
    return true;
  }
```

And this is all app_localizations.dart file

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  final Locale locale;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate = _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;

  Map flattenTranslations(Map<String, dynamic> json, [String prefix = '']) {
    final Map<String, String> translations = {};
    json.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
      if (value is Map) {
        translations.addAll(flattenTranslations(value, '$prefix$key.'));
      } else {
        translations['$prefix$key'] = value.toString();
      }
    });
    return translations;
  }

  Future<bool> load() async {
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/i18n/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    _localizedStrings = flattenTranslations(jsonMap);
    return true;
  }

  String translate(String key) {
    return _localizedStrings[key] ?? key;
  }
}

class _AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return ['en', 'pl'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();
    return localizations;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

Comment: That is the correct answer if you want nested translations and access them by the following pattern: X.Y.Z. 

Note: Remember to NOT put dots in your translation keys.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**First Method:**

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(“about”);
```

And change your translate function to this:

```
  String translate(String key) {
// Returns a localized text
  return _localizedValues[“Information”][key];
 }
```

Or you can do this:

**Second Method:**

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(”Information”,“about”);
```

And change your translate function to this:

```
 String translate(String parentkey, String nestedKey) {
// Returns a localized text
  return _localizedValues[parentKey][nestedKey];
 }
```

[This](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter-for-beginners-8074a68d7a79) might help.

Also, [This](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) is a good article to learn how to parse complex json files

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

After trying the code, I could understand the problem.

The problem is your _localizedValues["Information"] will be a String not a map becuase we converted the value to value.toString() and that's why you cannot use a second key because the returned object is not a Map but it's a String.

So _localizedValues["Information"] is "{about: About}".

To solve the problem, use the code below:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> _localizedValues; //your values are not String anymore and we use dynamic instead
Future<bool> load() async {
    // Load a language JSON file from the 'i18n' folder
    String value = await rootBundle.loadString('i18n/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(value);
    _localizedValues = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value); //not value.toString() so the value will be a map
    });
    return true;
  }
String translate(String parentkey, String nestedKey) {
    // Returns a localized text
      return _localizedValues[parentKey][nestedKey];
     }
```

And then you have to get "About" from the code below:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Information','about');
```

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. With the first method, You can access the data of “Information” key and with the key you’re passing, You get the value. With second method, You can access any nestedKey value inside a parentKey.

Comment: An error ocucured at the `nestedKey` part. `String` can't be assigned to `int`.

Comment: I thought I can access to the nested data like this `_localizedValues[parentKey][0].nestedKey` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: What you can do is that you can print your _localizedValues so you can see the structure of it. Then you have to use the appropriate keys to get the value. https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter-for-beginners-8074a68d7a79 can help. You’re welcome to show me the structure of _localizedValues and I try to help you further.

Comment: Thanks I will do it anyway but this article cannot be found..

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51 this is also helpful.

Comment: any updates on this? I'm also trying to access my nested json i18n in my localization translate function @Morez

Comment: the error i'm getting is I use the _localizedStrings[parentKey][key]. with the same nested structure @Ooto had above. this is the error The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Comment: like the question. I assume theres something I should do for `_localizedValues` function

Comment: @Yuhao I don't know how _localizedValues is structure so the problem might be that __localizedStrings[parentKey] returns a list instead of a map. The best thing to do is to print _localizedValues and have a look at its structure and pass the keys accordingly

Comment: if your _localizedValues is a map like the question, You have to be able to access the values by using the keys. Have a look at the links I posted in the comments to see what I mean

Comment: I did print out `_localizedValues`. Basically I got a `Map` inside another `Map`. All I'm trying to do is to access the value using nested in the second `Map`. I will take a look at the Medium link you posted

Comment: @Yuhao I understand what you mean and I really don't know why you are getting an error. Just try it in DartPad and write the code as _localizedValue = the map in the question and print _localizedValue["Information]["about"] and you have to get "About" as result.

Comment: The issue here is this. in my `AppLocalizations` class I have the code to map the value. Since I have them nested right now. It has change. For example. this is what I have right now. ```_localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, dynamic value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });``` this is wrong. apparent, because I'm maping a `map` inside another map.

Comment: @Yuhao Please have a look at my updated answer to see the problem and the solution

Comment: I did. still same kinda errors. also how do you initialize your `_localizedValues`? Mine is `Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;` but now since we have nested Map. it should change

Comment: I would assume it's `Map<String, dynamic> _localizedStrings `

Comment: @Yuhao yes sorry my bad. It has to be Map<String,dynamic> in order to make it work

Comment: YESSSSSS. I got it working! made few slight changes because I have type enforcing on my project

Comment: few things I wanna point out. you can modify your answer based on this: 1. the translate function should be `(_localizedValues[parentKey][nestedkey]).toString()` since you are return `String` not `dynamic`

Comment: 2. I'm enforcing types so `_localizedValues = jsonMapTest.map<String, dynamic>((key, dynamic value) {
      return MapEntry<String, dynamic>(key, value);
    });`

Comment: Because our value of _localizedValues[parentKey][nestedkey] is a String itself so I didn’t use toString(). I’m happy I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to access nested JSON regardless of depth. Just modify your translate method like so:

```
  String translate(String key) {
    List<dynamic> keys = key.split('.');
    var value = keys.fold(_localizedValues, (obj, key) => obj[key]);
    return value;
  }
```

Then you are able to access your nested JSON in your code like this:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('key1.key2.key3');
```

Just make sure there won't be any periods in your JSON keys

Comment: While this is great, maybe try getting rid of the period problem. Maybe have the keys as seperate arguments?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `easy_localization` flutter package for localization you can access object value from JSON like below with dot notation

> `"Information.about".tr()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, it looks like @Morez answer but it works for me:

```
  Map<String,dynamic> _localizedValues;
  Map<String,dynamic> _localizedValues2;

  Future<void> load() async {
    String jsonStringValues = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/jsonLanguages/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    //print(jsonStringValues);
    Map<String,dynamic> mappedJson = json.decode(jsonStringValues);
    _localizedValues = mappedJson.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value));
  }

  String translate(String key,String subkey){
    String test = _localizedValues[key].toString();
    test = test.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(\b\w+( +\w+)*\b)|(\b\w+\b)'), (match) {return '"${match.group(0)}"';});
    //print(test);
    Map<String,dynamic> mappedJson2 = json.decode(test);
    _localizedValues2 = mappedJson2.map((subkey, value) => MapEntry(subkey, value));
    return _localizedValues2[subkey];
  }
```