# Dart: Can't access to nested map object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter application and I can't access to nested map object in `dart`. 
My code is as below.

```
 Map<String, String> _localizedValues;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    // Load a language JSON file from the 'i18n' folder
    String value = await rootBundle.loadString('i18n/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(value);
    _localizedValues = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });
    return true;
  }

  String translate(String parent, String key) {
    // Returns a localized text
    return _localizedValues[parent][key];
  }
```

And error occurs `[key]` this part. It says

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

JSON file is like this.

```
{
     "Parent": {
         "key": "key"
     }
 }
```

What am I wrong with this?

Comment: `[parent][key]` one of those accepting `int` not `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will propose a different solution to this problem that might be easier for you to work with.
You can simply flatten the multidimensional json object before working with it.

```
Map<String, String> _localizedValues;

Map flattenTranslations(Map<String, dynamic> json, [String prefix = '']) {
    final Map<String, String> translations = {};
    json.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
      if (value is Map) {
        translations.addAll(flattenTranslations(value, '$prefix$key.'));
      } else {
        translations['$prefix$key'] = value.toString();
      }
    });
    return translations;
  }

  Future<bool> load() async {
    // Load a language JSON file from the 'i18n' folder
    String value = await rootBundle.loadString('i18n/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(value);
    _localizedValues = flattenTranslations(jsonMap);
    return true;
  }
```

You will get a simple Map object that will contain all the keys of your json with every subtree key prefixed by their parent's key.

For example:

```
    {
  "Parent": {
    "key": "key",
    "key1": "key",
    "key2": "key",
    "key3": "key",
    "someOtherKey": {
      "key213": "keyeye",
      "oneMoreLevel": {
        "key123412": "asdasdasd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will convert to a map with "Parent.someOtherKey.oneMoreLevel.key123412" key included.
After this you can use this function to get the translation:

```
    String translate(String key) {
    // Returns a localized text or KEY if there's no localization
    return _localizedValues[key] ?? key;
  }

print(translate('Parent.someOtherKey.oneMoreLevel.key123412'));
```

Comment: hmm it doesn't work. Still cannot access to the nested object and it just return `key`

Comment: The error message is `A non-null String must be provided to a Text Widget.` when I removed `?? key` this part so it doesn't access to the value I want to get.

Comment: It's because a Text widget can not accept a null value to display. You can change ```?? key``` to ```?? ''``` so it will return an empty string. ?? is a null-aware operator that will return the second operand if the first one is NULL.

Comment: I mean this way can't get access to the nested value so the error happens.

Comment: Update your first post with the new code you're using.

Comment: change the return of your translate function to ```return _localizedValues[key] ?? '';``` and print your _localizedValues to see it's content

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually it worked! I needed to restart the emulator..

Comment: But I still don't get how your code works.. Is there any reference to figure this out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210578/discussion-between-thepeanut-and-ooto).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data format:

```
{
     "Parent": {
         "key": "key"
     }
 }
```

As a example it should be something like this:

```
{"a": {"a": "4"}, "b": {"b": "5"}}
```

What you are doing by this line: `MapEntry(key, value.toString());` is, you are converting the inner map (`{"a": "4"}`) to `String`. That's why you are seeing that error.

Try removing `.toString()` from `MapEntry(key, value.toString())`.

Let me know if that doesnot work.

Comment: @Ooto Are you sure about the data format? Can you share a sample?

Comment: Does the problem really come from json? I am wondering becasue the error occurs on `translate` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
_localizedValues = jsonMap.forEach((key, value) {
  return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
});
```

Comment: How do you assign a `void` type to a variable? I mean pointless here

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25725126)