# Flutter: Localization with i18n() for Json file many levels

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

I use localization 2.1.0 (https://pub.dev/packages/localization). I have a file en_US.json:

```
"home": {
        "welcome text": "This text is in english",
        "my page": "My page"
    }
```

How to call "welcome text".i18n() from "home" ?

```
String text = 'welcome text'.i18n(); // home?
print(text) // prints 'This text is in english'
```

Thanks

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60915140/flutter-internationalization-how-to-access-to-nested-data-in-json

Comment: Thanks @MrShakila, but I would like find a method for i18n() function. If there's no other way, I'll use yours.